# Flutter redirect url, Salesforce oauth

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am creating a Flutter app (Android) and authenticating towards Salesforce

I am using this package for the oauth (authorization code grant flow), https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2_client

I have created the connected app in Salesforce were I define the callback url where the token response is received. The problem is that I need to define an actual with http(s) url so when I authorize it will open browser and redirect to a site where I will intercept the token

Is there really no other way to get this working than creating a site for this purpose and somehow picking the response from there. There is no way in Android to override that https and redirect to a custom schema ? Or are there any other ways to get this working ? Any help very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are able to set the callback url to a custom schema in Salesforce after all.